# Get only part of string

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a string like this:

```
$myString = "line40";
```

Where the value 40 is variable (I have a set of random numbers).

I would like to get ONLY the number 40 (or any other random numer - 40 is just an example).

Just like this:

```
$newString = 40;
```

I tried to do using a regular expression but I failed... Please, someone can help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are there quotes around `line40`?

Comment: Oh yes.. I forgot them only here. Thanks!

Comment: `you failed` - More details please

Comment: jnylen - I was trying like this: preg_replace('/line(.*)here/',$string);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newString = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $myString);
```

The regular expression `\D` matches anything that isn't a digit. This replaces them all with nothing.

Comment: Hey.. Well done! Thank you very much! 
Actually my solution was "ALMOST" correct! LOL

Comment: Thanks again! I'll set your answer as the best answer as long as it's possible (stackoverflow requires 9 minutes)

Comment: If you ever have strings like `word1e20` then you might be better off with a stricter regex like `/^\D+`.

Answer (score 0):

try `preg_match()`

```
$myString = 'line40';
preg_match('/([0-9])+/', $myString, $m);
echo $m[0]; // 40
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The solution above worked fine! Thanks a lot, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

How about this, You can use `filters`

```
$myString = "line40";
$myString = filter_var($myString, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo $myString; //output: 40
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php